# Grammar agreement help

Tags: verb-agreement

I am having a very hard time finding the error in one of the two sentences below. I thought they were both correct, however one of them is incorrect.

1. As you requested, here are some documentaries about famous magicians.
2. The flock of crows, their black wings glistening in the sunlight, is feeding greedily on the corn in the field.

My thoughts: 1. The only error I could think of is "per" as you requested. 2. I believe i'm correct in assuming that "flock" is singular, therefore indicating that the term "is feeding" is correct.

Which sentence is incorrect?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps the "error" lies in referencing the ***flock of crows*** with plural ***their** wings* and singular ***is** feeding* within the same sentence. Purely as a matter of style, I'd standardise on the plural - but then as a Brit I'm quite happy to treat singular nouns as plurals wherever this seems more appropriate from the *semantic* perspective.

Comment: if you ask me: in no. 1, you need to say "...as you have requested...", and in no. 2, pick a number for *flock*, either singular or plural and stick to it.

Comment: @jlovegren thank you for your advice. I'll be sure to keep that in mind when i'm dealing with questionable plural or singular words.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I think you've found the grammatical error. But I much prefer that version to *"The flock of crows, its black wings glistening ..."*. This disagreement between *"their"* and the verb is not unusual in American English.

Comment: @Peter: I wouldn't have thought *many* AmE speakers would be "happy" with ***its*** in the first position, in this exact context. But I suspect *on average* they might be "**less unhappy**", because of the way AmE tends to favour consistent use of singular for ***a** group, **a** family*, etc. So that might explain why some over-zealous pedantic teacher sees an "error" in the usage as cited. If not, maybe they think the problem is the attempt to link ***their*** back to preceding ***crows***, which can't really be thus "abstracted" from the complete NP ***flock of crows***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the sentence, "The entire class of boys was silenced by her outrage" the class is considered a single unit.  In the sentence, Some boys in the class were silenced by her outrage." the members within the class are not a unit but more than one was silenced.  The crow sentence isn't quite as clear but it refers to a unit who were all performing the same action as a unit so I would say the use of the singular is likely preferable.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. The cited example *does* use the singular *(**is** feeding)*, so that can't be the source of the "error". Are you suggesting it should therefore start with *"The flock of crows, **its** black wings glistening..."*?

Comment: No, I was agreeing that it should be singular so that couldn't be  the error and he should look elsewhere for the error.  Sorry I was unclear.

Answer (score 2):

*A murder of crows*, I would say.

> 1. [List of collective nouns in English.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_collective_nouns_in_English)
> 2. [The Word Detective - A Murder of Crows](http://www.word-detective.com/2009/02/murder-of-crows-etc/).
> 3. [A Murder of Crows - documentary film.](http://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CDsQtwIwBQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3Ds472GjbLKQ4&ei=GNNtVM2DK8ahgwTn-IOYDw&usg=AFQjCNFi2nMCoa6EVvn13af4F_2Keby4Ig&sig2=M91PEGqIMNyCEi51yPkN)

Comment: You might say that, but the evidence is that [the vast majority use "flock"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+flock+of+crows%2Ca+murder+of+crows&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20flock%20of%20crows%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20murder%20of%20crows%3B%2Cc0). I note that "murder" has become much more popular recently (probably because people like to *cite* such "terms of venery", not because they actually use them in real life), but it's still relatively uncommon. And many instances will be dictionary definitions, etc., not "genuine" uses.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree with you about terms of venery, but "a murder of crows" seems to be one of the best known. Not that people use it ("Oh, look at that murder of crows") but perhaps because of the poetic image it creates.

Comment: I quite agree "murder of crows" has become quite well-known over recent decades (as shown by my NGram link). I don't disagree with what you *say* - I just don't think it's a credible reason why someone might have told OP there's an error.

Comment: @FumbleFingers thank you for all of your input! I've never heard of a "murder" until you brought it up.

Comment: @sloth1111  My money is on this. Like FF I'd also say the term  *crows* invites the plural verb as in "are feeding" but this is subjective and much depends on one's dialect. Whereas *murder* is arguably the "most correct" collective noun. Centaurus I would provide a link as extra evidence.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Here you are.

Comment: @Mari-Lou: I see no justification whatsoever for suggesting ***murder** of crows* is "more correct". As OED puts it, it's *One of many **alleged** group names found in late Middle English glossarial sources. **Apparently revived in the 20th century***. It's not really even true to say it's "revived" in the full sense. I must have heard this word+meaning combination mentioned in conversation *thousands* of times over the years, but I'm quite sure I've *never* heard it used "naturally", of an actual flock of crows. It's just a quaint piece of medieval vocabulary trivia.

Comment: @FumbleFingers it's the OP's initial sentence which led me to make that statement *I am having a very hard time finding the error in* **one** *of the two sentences below*. Otherwise, where else could the "error" be. I might go for the "are feeding" but I do not know if the test paper (if it is one) is American or not. However, after carefully re-reading your comment "referencing the flock of crows with plural **their** wings and singular **is** feeding" perhaps that is where the error lies.

Comment: @Mari-Lou: Look no further than the link in my first comment under the question. It's there to explain my downvote, which certainly isn't because I think ***murder of crows*** is "incorrect". Particularly over the past few decades it's become very widely known - but as my NGram link shows, it's all relative. And relative to the standard ***flock of crows*** it's still "rare". Quite apart from the point I keep making, that most (written *or* spoken) instances are actually "mention" rather than "use". What's in this answer is true, but it's not the answer to OP's question.